# Data inside GetxController always returns null or Empty when used inside a GetBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, flutter-getx

I am trying to get data from a `List` inside a `GetxController` but it keeps returning null/Empty whenever I try to access it inside a GetBuilder even when I already assigned a value to it. Inside the `GetxController` I can print out the value but when I want to use it it returns null/Empty

```
class BankController extends GetxController implements GetxService {
  BankRepo bankRepo = BankRepo();
  List<Bank> banks = [];

 
  Future<void> getBanks() async {
    ResponseModel response = await bankRepo.banks();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(banks);    // => []
      banks = (response.data as List).map((e) => Bank.fromJson(e)).toList();
      print(banks);   // => [Instance of 'Bank', Instance of 'Bank', Instance of 'Bank', Instance of 'Bank', Instance of 'Bank', .....
      update();
    }
  }

}
```

**To Reproduce**:

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

- Call the getBanks function from BankController
- Get banks from BankController in add_bank.dart eg
  BankController().banks
- Print it to terminal, it returns empty List

Expected behavior:
After calling the `getBanks` function from `BankController`, a data is been assigned to `List<Bank> banks = [];`, then I create a `GetBuilder` inside `add_bank.dart` to get the data inside `List<Bank> banks = [];` and add them to my Dropdown. The dropdown will then display the list of all the banks.

Flutter Version:

```
Flutter Channel stable, v2.10.3
```

Getx Version:

```
get: ^4.6.5
```

Minimal reproduce code:
`add_bank.dart`:

```
class AddBankView extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddBankView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddBankView> createState() => _AddBankViewState();
}

class _AddBankViewState extends State<AddBankView> {
  Bank selectedBank = Bank(name: "Select Bank", code: "");

  @override
  void initState() {
    getBanks();
    super.initState();
  }

  getBanks() async {
    await BankController().getBanks();
    BankController ctn = Get.find<BankController>();
    print(ctn.banks); // => []
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: customAppbar("New Bank"),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),


            child: GetBuilder<BankController>(
                init: BankController(),
                builder: (bankController) {
                  print(bankController.banks); // => []
                  return Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                            child: GFDropdown(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                              border: const BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.transparent,
                                  width: 0,
                                  style: BorderStyle.none),
                              dropdownButtonColor: Colors.transparent,
                              dropdownColor:
                                  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
                              value: selectedBank,
                              icon: Icon(
                                IconlyBold.arrowDownCircle,
                                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
                                size: 22,
                              ),
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedBank = value as Bank;
                                });
                              },
                              items: bankController.banks
                                  .map((Bank value) => DropdownMenuItem<Bank>(
                                        value: value,
                                        child: CustomText(value.name,
                                            color: theme.secondary
                                                .withOpacity(0.85)),
                                      ))
                                  .toList(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]);
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Bind Controllers in `get_init.dart`:

```
initControllers() {
  //Repositories
  Get.lazyPut(() => BankRepo());

  //Controllers
  Get.lazyPut(() => BankController());
}
```

`main.dart`:

```
void main() async {
  initControllers();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I ask you guys, how can I solve it. If you have any questions you can ask me.

Comment: Plz always include your imports, so that we know exactly what packages you've used! (I've sometimes assumed a different package which used a class with the same name, and it made my answer useless... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bit tricky when using `Get.lazyPut` or `Get.put` or instead `Get.create` and depending on the case that you want it to act. Like `Get.lazyPut` will not create the instance at the time, and will create it when you call `Get.find`.

And in your case, this is the code from your question.

```
  getBanks() async {
    await BankController().getBanks();
    BankController ctn = Get.find<BankController>();
    print(ctn.banks); // => []
  }
```

when you call `await BankController().getBanks();` you literally create a new instance of `BankController` using its constructor. and then on the line below, you create another instance of `BankController` but using the GetX dependency injector (`lazyPut` factory). So the instance `ctn` and the instance created in this `BankController().getBanks()` is completely  different  instance. and obviously will produce empty banks.

Get.lazyPut, or Get.put didn't simply make all of the class become singleton, you have to call `Get.find` and use the instance from it to make it act as a single instance.

So, in conclusion, your code should be like this:

```
    BankController ctn = Get.find<BankController>();
    await ctn.getBanks();
    print(ctn.banks);
```

More detail about the difference between put, lazyPut, and create can be found here:

https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/dependency_management.md#differences-between-methods

Answer (score 1):

Have you used BankController in any other page?

If not, use Get.put instead of Get.find :-

```
final BankController bankControl = Get.put(BankController());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways on doing this either you make it a service or a controller.

**Service approach:**

```
class BankService extends GetxService {}
```

*main.dart file*

```
await Get.putAsync<BankService>(() async => BankService());
```

*add_bank_view.dart file*

```
getBanks() async {
   final ctn = Get.find<BankService>();
   await ctn.getBanks(); 
   print(ctn.banks); // => []
}
```

**Controller approach:**

```
class BankController extends GetxController {}
```

*add_bank_view.dart file*

```
final controller = Get.put(BankController());

getBanks() async {
   await controller.getBanks(); 
   print(controller.banks); // => []
}
```